# how to swap the content of two files in PHP

Tags: php, filesystems, rename, fopen, swap

I want to swap the content of two files using php. but it seems that the file executions are processed on the end of the script and in a strange way. because it always either write the content into only one file or nothing happens, but the files were rewritten.

i tried the following:

```
rename($file1,$file2_temp);
rename($file2,$file1); // replace the file1
rename($file2_temp,$file2); // save the temporary file2 as the file2
```

i also tried to put it into `fopen` and `flock` statements, but it didnt work.

does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: The idea is ok, maybe you dont have the rights

Comment: Shot in the dark - try placing a `usleep(100)` between each line...

Comment: also: rename($file2,$file1); // replace the file1 does not replace file1, it replaces file2 name ! with file1 name;

Comment: Tried your code and it works for me without problems. Did you enter the right paths and file names for variables ($file1, $file2_temp and $file1)? Also check that you have right to do this. Rename function return true if success and false otherwise so add for example this:
$ren1 = rename($file1, $file2_temp);
$ren2 = rename($file2, $file1);
$ren3 = rename($file2_temp, $file2);
echo "Out: $ren1 $ren2 $ren3";
it should echo 3x 1 (true) like 1 1 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out, The code was right, the problem was that my script runs twice somehow and therefor it was overwriting the files forth and back again :(
i now have to figure out why its running twice, but thanks to you all!

Answer (score 2):

While using file names, make sure u use full path, Eg:

```
rename ("/folder/file.ext", "/folder/newfile.ext");
```

Comment: thanks. but yes, i use full paths.. could you check that on your server?